# How can I capture the console output of an Azure function that crashes immediately?

Tags: visual-studio, azure, azure-functions, .net-standard

I have a v2 Azure function. When I run the project in debug, the console window opens, I see the Azure logo spin out, then some red text and the whole thing shuts down before I've had a chance to see the exception. Is there any way to capture what's writing to the console window? (Or are there any other suggestions as to how I might capture the exception and figure out what's going on?)

I have the following packages installed:

- Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Storage v3.0.1
- Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions v1.0.23
- NETStandardLibrary v2.0.3
- SimpleInjector v4.3.0

I am running the Azure Storage Emulator and Visual Studio in Administrator mode. For all of my connections I'm using `UseDevelopmentStorage=true`.

My launchSettings.json file looks like this:

```
{
  "profiles": {
    "MyProject.Functions": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "commandLineArgs": "C:\\Users\\someone\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\azure-functions-core-tools\\bin\\func.dll host start --port 7077 --pause-on-start"
    }
  }
}
```

Please let me know if there's any other information I need to provide.

Comment: It would be something to update your Storage Emulator version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggestion is to delete your `launchSettings.json`.

By default Function project doesn't need this file and automatically downloads and works with latest function core tools, as long as we have installed latest `Azure Functions and Web Jobs Tools`. Find it on VS menus>Tools>Extensions and Updates, right now see its version is 15.10.2046 in VS 15.8.7.

We can see the default profile for Function project is

```
"<YourFunctionAppName>": {
  "commandName": "Project"
}
```

If you want to use cli installed by npm, try following settings.

```
"<YourProfileName>": {
  "commandName": "Executable",
  "executablePath": "%APPDATA%\\npm\\node_modules\\azure-functions-core-tools\\bin\\func.exe",
  "commandLineArgs": "host start --port 7077"
}
```

`--port` is optional and default is 7071. There's no argument called `--pause-on-start`.

Answer (score 0):

With v2 you will get an error in Functions CLI if we have not updated the Storage Emulator version. But this error will not stop testing of the function in local.The logs usually go in to TableStorage in Emulator.

Error similar to this screenshot. [image]